# Wordpress plugin to send secure mails/or messages from the web-member login area

Tags: wordpress

Currently looking for a wordpress plugin to:

Enable a member of an organization to send secure mails/or messages from the web-member login area, with attached documents/files that contains sensitive information to the organization secretary.

Comment: "Secure mails" is a bit vague. A GPG encrypted mail can be considered secure, however, you'd first have to be sure the organization's secretary can actually decrypt this (has the appropriate software and keyring available). It would probably be better to develop a plugin allowing web-members to upload such documents and only access their own files. For the secretary role, allow access to download all files. Of course, those files must not be kept in a place that is accessible by just knowing the link - but rather download based on active login with secretary role.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.